# Spring IDE Bean Graphs is blank for blueprint configuration file

Tags: spring-tool-suite, blueprint-osgi

I have installed Spring IDE 3.7.2 (Core + OSGi Extension), in Eclipse Mars SR1 Java EE.

I am writing blueprint bundles, and the tooling seams to work except for Beans Graph, who remains empty (with no errors in error log),

With a similar configuration for spring, the beans graph is displayed

After investigating this, it seems there is no org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler implementation provided for http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 namespace.

I manage to write a "quick and dirty" implementation based on one I found in eclipse gemini blueprint as a proof of concept

Is it something you could be interested in as a contribution ?

Comment: I would recommend to open a bug report at our issuetracker (https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS) and attach a sample project that illustrates the issue. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have opened https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4252, thanks